# using row_number() in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following data and I am trying to count each record whenever a combo of userid+customerid appear.  If the same combo returns in between other combos, I want to start the counter from one again.  However, when I use row_number() in the following code in Db2, I can't seem to get it working so that the counter is restarting at 1 for each userid+customerid appearing over time.  Does anyone have other suggestions?  Thank you so much.

[image]

```
select userid, customer, event_name, event_timestamp,     
       row_number() over (partition by user_id, customer_number
                          order by  event_timestamp) as steps_rownum
from trackhist
order by userid, event_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select userid, customer, event_name, event_timestamp,
       row_number() over (partition by userid, customer, grp
                          order by event_timestamp) as steps
from
(
    select t.*,
           (row_number() over (order by event_timestamp) -
            row_number() over (partition by userid, customer order by event_timestamp)
           ) as grp
    from trackhist t
) t
order by userid, event_timestamp
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Note that the demo uses SQL Server, as DB2 is not an option with Rextester (at least for now).  The query should work in DB2 however, assuming `ROW_NUMBER()` behaves the same in both databases.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tim!  This works :D. Also, Thanks for the suggestions on post editing too.